# Wordpress plugin hijacked database, how to clean?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wordpress

My database has been hijacked by the All-in-One Event Calendar plugin from the WP plugin repository. The plugin was removed, but has left lots of junk in the `wp_options` table. While I could remove some of the options, the plugin has injected some serious stuff into the option id's I believe are of core relevance: `user_roles` (`option_id` 99) and `cron` (`option_id` 106).

Below is the cron `option_id`. Can someone please have a look and see how that mess can be cleaned up? `ai1ec` (All-in-One Event Calendar), is the plugin. I am at a loss here really.

```
(106,'cron','a:12:{i:1351390114;a:1:{s:12:\"ai1ec_u_cron\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:6:\"hourly\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:3600;}}}i:1351390525;a:1:{s:25:\"ai1ec_facebook_cron_pages\";a:1:{s:32:\"5b7cb91948f8bf686b1a2b49d260e23e\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:1:{i:0;s:4:\"page\";}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}i:1351392325;a:1:{s:26:\"ai1ec_facebook_cron_groups\";a:1:{s:32:\"440efcc24b7250fee903fb2f69981914\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:1:{i:0;s:5:\"group\";}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}i:1351392373;a:3:{s:16:\"wp_version_check\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}s:17:\"wp_update_plugins\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}s:16:\"wp_update_themes\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}i:1351394125;a:1:{s:25:\"ai1ec_facebook_cron_users\";a:1:{s:32:\"fa7faa01ef3155dd51574f1d1e8eddd9\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:1:{i:0;s:4:\"user\";}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}i:1351424436;a:1:{s:12:\"ai1ec_n_cron\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:5:\"daily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:86400;}}}i:1351425083;a:1:{s:10:\"ai1ec_cron\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:5:\"daily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:86400;}}}i:1351431925;a:1:{s:26:\"ai1ec_facebook_cron_events\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:10:\"twicedaily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:43200;}}}i:1351435602;a:1:{s:19:\"wp_scheduled_delete\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:5:\"daily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:86400;}}}i:1351450159;a:1:{s:30:\"wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:5:\"daily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:86400;}}}i:1351465714;a:1:{s:12:\"ai1ec_n_cron\";a:1:{s:32:\"40cd750bba9870f18aada2478b24840a\";a:3:{s:8:\"schedule\";s:5:\"daily\";s:4:\"args\";a:0:{}s:8:\"interval\";i:86400;}}}s:7:\"version\";i:2;}','yes')
```

The `user_roles` id looks even worse. `ai1ec`, again, is all over the place. There is also an "Event Contributor" default user role in the admin area which cannot be deleted.

```
(99,'xxxxxxxuser_roles','a:6:{s:13:\"administrator\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:13:\"Administrator\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:79:{s:13:\"switch_themes\";b:1;s:11:\"edit_themes\";b:1;s:16:\"activate_plugins\";b:1;s:12:\"edit_plugins\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_users\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_files\";b:1;s:14:\"manage_options\";b:1;s:17:\"moderate_comments\";b:1;s:17:\"manage_categories\";b:1;s:12:\"manage_links\";b:1;s:12:\"upload_files\";b:1;s:6:\"import\";b:1;s:15:\"unfiltered_html\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_posts\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_posts\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_pages\";b:1;s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:8:\"level_10\";b:1;s:7:\"level_9\";b:1;s:7:\"level_8\";b:1;s:7:\"level_7\";b:1;s:7:\"level_6\";b:1;s:7:\"level_5\";b:1;s:7:\"level_4\";b:1;s:7:\"level_3\";b:1;s:7:\"level_2\";b:1;s:7:\"level_1\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_pages\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_pages\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_pages\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_pages\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_posts\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_posts\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_posts\";b:1;s:18:\"read_private_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"read_private_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_users\";b:1;s:12:\"create_users\";b:1;s:17:\"unfiltered_upload\";b:1;s:14:\"edit_dashboard\";b:1;s:14:\"update_plugins\";b:1;s:14:\"delete_plugins\";b:1;s:15:\"install_plugins\";b:1;s:13:\"update_themes\";b:1;s:14:\"install_themes\";b:1;s:11:\"update_core\";b:1;s:10:\"list_users\";b:1;s:12:\"remove_users\";b:1;s:9:\"add_users\";b:1;s:13:\"promote_users\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_theme_options\";b:1;s:13:\"delete_themes\";b:1;s:6:\"export\";b:1;s:16:\"read_ai1ec_event\";b:1;s:16:\"edit_ai1ec_event\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_others_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_private_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:27:\"edit_published_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:18:\"delete_ai1ec_event\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_others_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:29:\"delete_published_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_private_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:20:\"publish_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:25:\"read_private_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:24:\"manage_events_categories\";b:1;s:18:\"manage_ai1ec_feeds\";b:1;s:19:\"switch_ai1ec_themes\";b:1;s:20:\"manage_ai1ec_options\";b:1;}}s:6:\"editor\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:6:\"Editor\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:49:{s:17:\"moderate_comments\";b:1;s:17:\"manage_categories\";b:1;s:12:\"manage_links\";b:1;s:12:\"upload_files\";b:1;s:15:\"unfiltered_html\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_posts\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_posts\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_pages\";b:1;s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:7:\"level_7\";b:1;s:7:\"level_6\";b:1;s:7:\"level_5\";b:1;s:7:\"level_4\";b:1;s:7:\"level_3\";b:1;s:7:\"level_2\";b:1;s:7:\"level_1\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_others_pages\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_pages\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_pages\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_pages\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_pages\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_others_posts\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_posts\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_posts\";b:1;s:18:\"read_private_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"delete_private_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"edit_private_pages\";b:1;s:18:\"read_private_pages\";b:1;s:16:\"read_ai1ec_event\";b:1;s:16:\"edit_ai1ec_event\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_others_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_private_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:27:\"edit_published_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:18:\"delete_ai1ec_event\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_others_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:29:\"delete_published_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_private_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:20:\"publish_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:25:\"read_private_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:24:\"manage_events_categories\";b:1;s:18:\"manage_ai1ec_feeds\";b:1;}}s:6:\"author\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:6:\"Author\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:25:{s:12:\"upload_files\";b:1;s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:1;s:20:\"edit_published_posts\";b:1;s:13:\"publish_posts\";b:1;s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:7:\"level_2\";b:1;s:7:\"level_1\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:1;s:22:\"delete_published_posts\";b:1;s:16:\"read_ai1ec_event\";b:1;s:16:\"edit_ai1ec_event\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:24:\"edit_others_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:25:\"edit_private_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:27:\"edit_published_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:18:\"delete_ai1ec_event\";b:1;s:19:\"delete_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:26:\"delete_others_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:29:\"delete_published_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:27:\"delete_private_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:20:\"publish_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:25:\"read_private_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:24:\"manage_events_categories\";b:1;s:18:\"manage_ai1ec_feeds\";b:1;}}s:11:\"contributor\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:11:\"Contributor\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:5:{s:10:\"edit_posts\";b:1;s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:7:\"level_1\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;s:12:\"delete_posts\";b:1;}}s:10:\"subscriber\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:10:\"Subscriber\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:2:{s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;}}s:21:\"ai1ec_event_assistant\";a:2:{s:4:\"name\";s:17:\"Event Contributor\";s:12:\"capabilities\";a:4:{s:4:\"read\";b:1;s:7:\"level_0\";b:1;s:17:\"edit_ai1ec_events\";b:1;s:18:\"delete_ai1ec_event\";b:1;}}}','yes'),
```

Comment: That data is in PHP's serialized storage format. If you know a little PHP, you can convert it back to structured data using [`unserialize`](http://us.php.net/unserialize), then you'll be able to remove the entries related to `ai1ec`, re-serialize the data and update the record.

Answer (score 1):

looking through the source of the plugin you can find the option names given to it during installation, quickest way to get rid of them all is to open your theme functions.php file

paste in:

```
delete_option('ai1ec_settings');
```

other options i seen

```
//from file:all-in-one-event-calendar\app\model\class-ai1ec-settings.php
update_option( 'ai1ec_settings', $this );
update_option( 'start_of_week', $this->week_start_day );
update_option( 'ai1ec_cron_version', get_option( 'ai1ec_cron_version' ) + 1 );
update_option( 'timezone_string', $this->timezone );
```

you can delete these also if you want.
when u update ur functions.php file either through apperance->editor or ftp, when u visit the site the functions file will run, and if the options are found, wordpress will delete them. :)

then just remove the call in your functions file..